# {Link} does not take to the correct URL in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning Reactjs, and there is a problem when I try to use {Link} to go to external websites.

```
<Link to={repo.html_url}>
{repo.name}
</Link>
```

Let's say the repo.html_url is 
https://github.com/ningmeng7998/SmartER-Project-Android-Frontend. 
Instead of taking me to this URL, it takes me to http://localhost:3000/profile/https://github.com/ningmeng7998/SmartER-Project-Android-Frontend, which adds localhost in front of it.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The primary way to allow users to navigate **around your application**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external links, just use `a` tag! as `<Link>` is only used for internal routes. [As you can see in the docs that React Router themselves used `a` tags for an external link instead of `Link`.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters)

```
<a href={repo.html_url}>
{repo.name}
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

*I'm assuming you're using [React Router's Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component, as it is not part of vanilla React.*

Currently, React Router `Link`s do not support external URLs, they're just for navigating internally in your app.  You'll want to use a standard HTML anchor tag.  Try this:

```
<a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
```

There's some discussion going on around the issue of `Link`s supporting external URLs [going on here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147) if you'd like to learn more or stay in the loop.

Another solution is to implement your own wrapper around `Link` that handles the logic (and in the end spits out a `<Link>` component for internal routes or `<a>` tag for external URLs).

Comment: That's why. Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ning consider accepting as answer if something solved your problem